# Set fontawesome icon from a variable - react

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I'm building a react application:

```
"react": "^16.0.0",
```

with font awesome integrated.

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
```

In a component, I want to set an icon from a const in another JSON file, but without variables it looks like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={Brand_icons.faJava} size="6x" transform="shrink-6"/>
```

I've imported FontAwesomeIcon and other libraries like this:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import * as Brand_icons from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

This is my const and I want to set these icon names in a loop:

```
const skills = [
  "faJava",
  "faPython",
  "faJsSquare",
  "faReact",
  "faPhp"
];
```

and here is the loop I used to get these icon:

```
{skills.map((skill, index) => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={Brand_icons.faJava} size="6x" transform="shrink-6"/>
  </div>
))}
```

I want to set the value from the skill variable instead of ***faJava***. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAwesome already exports **fab** from **'@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'** which contains all the icons.

You can change the import like this:

```
import { fab as brandIcons } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

And change the render like this:

```
{skills.map(skill => (
        <FontAwesomeIcon key={skill} icon={brandIcons[skill]} size="6x" transform="shrink-6" />
))}
```

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Actually, it's working pretty fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/fab-example-ty8t31?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Not for me https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wescoff-hyd1yo?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: You have to use `faCircleExclamation` instead of `circle-exclamation` for the `i` variable initialization.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/

Comment: That page does not explain that the value of the string variable is different to the icon name.

Comment: I meant this one: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons. It explains that in order to use the kebab-version of the icon class you should imprort them globally in advance. Otherwise, you have to use individual imports.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit confusing, given that when you look for a specific icon in the website, the React snippet uses that version by default, without making it clear that you need to run that global import.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals in js to achieve above task.

```js
{skills.map((skill, index) => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={`${Brand_icons}.${skill}`} size="6x" transform="shrink-6"/>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: now the icons are not showing. When printing it, the error is **Could not find icon**

Comment: This does not work: string is not assignable to IconProp.

Answer (score 1):

If Brand_icons is an array and you are looping skills, the prop icon should be equal to this: icon=Brand_icons[skill]

Comment: Brand_icons is a module, using it returns an object, but not the fontawesome icon

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my const to:

```
const skills = [
  Brand_icons.faJava,
  Brand_icons.faPython,
  Brand_icons.faJsSquare,
  Brand_icons.faHtml5,
  Brand_icons.faCss3Alt,
  Brand_icons.faPhp,
];
```

Then called the variable:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={skill} size="6x" transform="shrink-6"/>
```